# A better way to change mysql values than <select>

Tags: php, html, forms

I have made a select code to update my database with:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table><tr><td style="border:1px solid #000;">
<select name="priv" id="priv">
<option value="<?php echo $pinDetails->is_private; ?>">(<?php echo $pinDetails->is_private; ?>)</option>
<option value="1">Private (1)</option>
<option value="0">Public (0)</option>
</select>
<input name="private" type="submit" id="private" value="Private">
</td></tr></table>
</form>
```

This basically allows me to change a post from public to private by selecting the appropriate option in the list. It displays the current value as the first option.

However, this code looks messy and I know the function could probably to achieved a way better way than clicking an option, something along the lines of a button which I can switch on or off like a switch?

What would I need to search for or what type of code would work for this? I'm more than willing to write the code myself given a point in the right direction.

Comment: A checkbox works perfectly. Caption it "Public" or "Private", where a status of checked means the item is on, and unchecked means it's off. (It's the way checkboxes work everywhere, so it won't confuse users.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want, i.e. often programmers use radio buttons and style them like a switch.

Maybe this could be of interest: http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

Also check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craig1000/cysCx/):

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch1">First switch</label>
</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" name="switch2" class="switch" />
    <label for="switch2">Second switch</label>
</div>
```